# Algorithm placing nodes in 2D - Diagram Creation

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, diagram, isomorphism

Is there an unlicensed algorithm for placing nodes/vertices in a compact, clear way, with nodes being close to each other without overlapping and having short edges and those with many links not being all in the center etc, i.e. all that matters in a good diagram?

In other words, how do I isomorph a graph in the most clearly arranged position?

Oh, and the nodes are rectangles (as I said, it's for a diagram) can differ in size depending on their content

Comment: you may try to see how JUNG draws graphs (http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/JUNGVisualizationGuide.html)

Comment: Basically, this is an unsolved problem. So you won't find any algorithm that can do this in the general case (neither "licensed" nor "unlicensed"). Even the [top commercial](http://www.yworks.com/yfiles) and [non-commerical](http://www.graphviz.org) solutions don't provide solutions that work for *any* graph. You need to be more specific than "a good diagram" to find a matching algorithm.

Comment: http://graphviz.org/